# How to change element "this" in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, this

I have this piece of code, which allows me to change the image by clicking on it.

```
$('img').click(function(){
    var src = this.src;
    this.src = src.indexOf('_b.jpg') == -1 ? src.replace('.jpg','_b.jpg') : src.replace('_b.jpg','.jpg');
});
```

I would prefer to click on another element to still be able to change the image. When I change the part in `$('myelement')`, I need to make sure that the part `var src = this.src;` refers to the image.

In what do I have to change the `this`?

Comment: Please include your HMTL code so we can see your context. I.e. is the image a child of the element you're clicking? A sibling? Neither?

Comment: You could create a function and then bind it's context to the image, or pass the image in as event data, or select the image using a jquery selector (or dom api methods)

Comment: does this == $(this)?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have **only one** `img` tag in your HTML:

```
$('myelement').click(function(){
  var src = $('img').attr('src');
  var newSrc = src.indexOf('_b.jpg') == -1 ? src.replace('.jpg','_b.jpg') : src.replace('_b.jpg','.jpg');
  $('img').attr('src', newSrc);
});
```

But generally it's better to select with more specific selector, like `id` or some unique `class` attribute, as you might want more images in the document - then `$('img')` will select an array of all images.

Answer (score 0):

In javascript `this` refers to *current object*, in other words *contex*. General practice is storing context into a variable so that when context changes, lets say by a dom event, you can still reach it.

```
 // stores context into that variable
 var that = this;
```

But apparently your question has nothing to do with `this`. If you need to change image attributes from another element, you need select the img tag and act on it.

```
 $('.another-element').click(function(){
     var newSrc = 'Here goes the new scr attribute';
     $('img').attr('src',newScr);
 });
```

You can use id or class for more precise selection.